# Printing greek letters using sympy in text

Tags: python, printing, sympy

Lets say I want to print something like

"I am pi"

where pi should really be the greek letter pi. With sympy I can do

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import pi
sympy.pprint(pi)
```

which gives the greek letter pi, but I have problems putting this into a text. For example

```
sympy.pprint("I am"+pi)
```

obviously doesn't work. I can convert the text to a sympy symbol sympy.Symbol('I am'), but then I will get

I am+pi

Comment: do you want to print a math Greek letter given its English name? Have you tried a dictionary: `d = {'pi': u'\U0001D6D1'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `pretty()`, which is the same as `pprint`, but it returns a string instead of printing it.

```
In [1]: pretty(pi)
Out[1]: 'π'

In [2]: "I am %s" % pretty(pi)
Out[2]: 'I am π'
```

If all you care about is getting the Unicode character, you can use the Python standard library:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER %s" % letter.upper()) # for lowercase letters
unicodedata.lookup("GREEK CAPITAL LETTER %s" % letter.upper()) # for uppercase letters
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unicodedata.lookup` to get the Unicode character. In your case you would do like this:

```
import unicodedata
print("I am " + unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER PI"))
```

This gives the following result:

```
I am π
```

If you want the capital letter instead, you should do `unicode.lookup("GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI"))`. You can replace `PI` with the name of any Greek letter.

Answer (score 1):

latex and str will both return a string

```
>>> latex(pi)
'\\pi'
>>> str(pi)
'pi'
```