# How to display Greek letters using sympy.printing.mathml

Tags: python, sympy, mathml

I use Python's `Sympy` module.

The Sympy module has a library called `sympy.printing.mathml`, which converts formulas into `mathml`.

However, I could not convert Greek letters such as α and β to mathml.

How can I solve this problem if I want to insert Greek letters into the formula?

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

I want to get mathml like example2 from python's formula like example1.

**example1**

```
S=abs(a)*(β-α)^3/6
```

**example2**

```
<math><mi>S</mi><mo>=</mo><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mfrac><mrow><mo>|</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>|</mo><mo>&#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--></mo><mo>(</mo><mo>&#x03b2;</mo><mo>-</mo><mo>&#x03b1;</mo><msup><mo>)</mo><mn>3</mn></msup></mrow><mrow><mn>6</mn></mrow></mfrac></mstyle></math>
```

I executed the following code.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
print(mathml(S=abs(a)*(β-α)^3/6,printer='presentation'))
```

Comment: Give us an example, what did you convert..what you can't convert...what is the input, expected output and so on!!

Comment: Just type them. MathML is still XML and can handle Unicode text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing greek letters using sympy in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483891/printing-greek-letters-using-sympy-in-text)

Comment: Have you tried something and encountered a problem? What exactly? It could be an actual problem or trying to display UTF8 text on a console that doesn't support UTF8

Comment: @YiBao that's a rather ... weird way of typing text. You can install the Greek keyboard on your OS and type the characters. Both Windows and Ubuntu have Greek keyboard support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal that supported copy/paste of Greek characters, I was able to create a variable with Greek name, e.g. `beta = Symbol('beta')` where `beta` was a literal Greek character. The output of the formula you gave -- using `**` instead of `^` is identical to the code generated when the symbols for alpha and beta are imported from abc:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import alpha, beta
>>> print(mathml(abs(a)*(beta-alpha)**3/6, printer='presentation'))
<mrow><mfrac><mrow><msup><mfenced><mrow><mrow><mo>-</mo><mi>&#945;</
o>+</mo><mi>&#946;</mi></mrow></mfenced><mn>3</mn></msup><mo>&Invisi
o><mrow><mfenced close="|" open="|"><mi>a</mi></mfenced></mrow></mro
</mfrac></mrow>
```